# Count of unmatched records between two Tables in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join

How to get the count of unmatched records between two Tables in PostgreSQL?

```
Create Table t1
(
 id integer NOT NULL,
 name text,
 address text
 );

Create Table t2
(
 name text,
 contact varchar(12)
 );

 insert into t1 values(1, 'A INc',  '29 Ave. Toronto, ON');
 insert into t1 values(2,  'B INc', '115 Street New York, NY');

 insert into t2 values('A Inc',  '123-456-7890');
 insert into t2 values('C INc', '234-567-8901');
```

How to fetch the row count of unmatched records through Query

Expected output:
      **count**
          **1**
The output of the result has to be Count :1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
select count(*) from t1 where name not in(select name from t2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use outer join to find the rows not belonging to a set.

```
select count(*)
from t1
right join t2
on t1.name = t2.name
where t1.name is null;
```